# Localization In Ext JS with Sencha CMD

Tags: extjs

I am trying to implement Localization in Ext JS using Sencha CMD using version 5.0.

I have added locale folder and corresponding content in that. I have modified app.json with locales and builds object and added output object based on which different bootstrap json will be built for each build configured in build object.

Not when i do sencha app build and then open the Appname/index.html and change locale via url i am able to achieve localization.

But when i open Appname/build/production/Appname/index.html and change the locale in url i am not able to change the app language by changing locale in url.

Any advise on how to go about it.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Well, without the error (if any) that you're seeing, it's a little hard to say. However, I'd look for packaging problems. The production build is very aggressive about trying to only include referenced code, and can easily miss files. Check the generated source to see if your locale files are even included. If they aren't, then add a reference somewhere.

Comment: Hi Robert, I am not seeing any error. But wen I did console.log in index.HTML in production folder for Ext.manifest it does not change with diff locale. But same thing changes in index.HTML in app folder. I ll post some snippet and validate file inclusion tomo n update here.

Comment: Can you post the code from your index.html that chooses which manifest to load?